# Redirect output to 3 different files based on content

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, stdout

I have some legacy `bash` code that I am running and want to insert print statements which should go to stdout. I want anything that *would have* gone to stdout to go to `out.out` and anything that *would have* gone to stderr to go to `err.err`.

Running `myCode.sh 2> err.err 1> out.out` will print everything out as normal, but I'd like to put in print statements like `echo "NewStatement: I am at this point in the code"` and then somehow pre-grep for `NewStatement` and send it to stdout, while everything else gets treated as normal.

In essence I would like to:

1) Send anything in `stdout` containing `NewStatement` to `stdout`

2) Send anything in `stdout` *not* containing `NewStatement` to `out.out`

3) Send anything in `stderr` to `err.err`

is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
>out.out

./myCode.sh 2> err.err 1> >(awk '!/^NewStatement/{print > "out.out"; next} 1')
```

`awk` command inside process substitution prints to `out.out` if line doesn't start with `NewStatement`. Otherwise lines starting with `NewStatement` are printed to `stdout`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can

```
myCode.sh 2>err.err | tee >(grep -v NewStatement > out.out) | grep NewStatement
```

The `tee` duplicates everything from his `stdin`, so

- tee-ed stream is filtered by `grep -v patt` (e.g. doesn't contain) and redirected
- the `stdout` if filtered by `grep patt` (e.g. only lines when contain)

This can be repeated any times, like

```
cmd | tee >(cmd1) >(cmd2) >(cmd3) | cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy.  First, the "beginner" solution.

Create a `wrapper` script (or wrapper function in your main script) which will contain something like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line || [[ $line ]]
do
  if
    [[ $line =~ NewStatement ]]
  then
    echo "$line"
  else
    echo "$line" >> out.out
  fi
done< <("$@" 2>err.err)
```

Then, simply call your script like this (assuming everything is executable and in the current directory :

```
./wrapper myCode.sh
```

The mode "advanced" solution uses a file descriptor to open the target file for writing.

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3> out.out # Open file descriptor 3 for writing to file

while read line || [[ $line ]]
do
  if
    [[ $line =~ NewStatement ]]
  then
    echo "$line"
  else
    echo "$line" >> &3
  fi
done< <("$@" 2>err.err)

exec 3>&- # Close file descriptor
```

You could have many file descriptors to perform output to many separate files based on arbitrary complex conditions.